# @mousemove event is triggered even after the pointer left the designated area

Tags: vuejs3, mouseevent, mousemove

I am working with Vue SFC and Composition API and my goal is to have a shiny-on-hover effect that follows the mouse when it hovers a specific `div` on the page.

I added a `@mousemove` directive on this `div`. Events are triggered when the mouse hovers the `div` (which is the expected behaviour) but my issue is that events continue to be triggered even after the mouse left the `div`

Here is the [Vue SFC playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) where I reproduced the issue and added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, that's a fun one: You are drawing the blue dot in a CSS `:after` of the container, and put it right under the cursor. However, it does still belong to the container. So basically a part of the container gets stuck to the cursor, so it is still hovering a child of the container, even outside it, and the `mousemove` event keeps firing.

When I move the mouse fast enough, I can escape the blue dot and the events stop. Similarly, I can pick it up again.

An easy fix (as suggested by @tao in the comments), is to stop the `:after` element from receiving pointer events:

```css
.ctn:after{
  pointer-events: none;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why not add `pointer-events: none` to `.ctn:after`?

Comment: @tao Ah, very nice, even makes the answer much more compact. Thank you!